# Google Map API v3 not being stylized

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I've tried searching around for a while, and I can't seem to find the answer.  I implemented the Google Maps API v3 into my website, which works.  However, when I try to stylize it (simply desaturate) it doesn't seem to work. I've tried a bunch of different tutorials, to no avail.  I'm using Twitter Bootstrap too, to save me a little work with CSS, if that would affect anything?  The website can bee seen [here](http://www.casprstudio.com/bootstrap).

Here's the script for the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var styles = [
      {
        featureType: "all", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { saturation: -100 }
        ]
      }
    ];

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.29900, -71.26232),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

  };
</script>
```

This is how I put it into my HTML farther down the page:

```
<div class="bg-blue">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 250px;"></div>
</div>
```

Like I said above, the map shows up, but the styling doesn't take effect.  Please let me know if you can be of any help.  I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created your styles but you have not applied them to your map...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map

```
function initialize() {

    var styles = [
      {
        featureType: "all", elementType: "all", stylers: [ { saturation: -100 }
        ]
      }
    ];

    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.29900, -71.26232),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: styles  // <-- add this
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

};
```

Comment: That solved it.  Thank you very much!  I must have just missed that every time I looked at the documentation... rookie mistake.  I owe you a cookie.

Comment: @Zack, instead of a cookie, I'll take an "up-vote" (click the up arrow).  Thanks.

Comment: I tried earlier, but I can't because I don't have a high enough reputation. Sorry... Gonna have to settle for the cookie unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `styles` property in your `mapOptions` object:

```
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.29900, -71.26232),
  zoom: 17,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  styles: styles
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bTZcS/